# Why kafka connect internal topic connect-offsets has 50 partitions and connect-status has 10?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As per reading the kafka connect documentation:

https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.3/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode

**config.storage.topic=connect-configs**

bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic connect-configs --replication-factor 3 --**partitions 1** --config cleanup.policy=compact

**offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets**

bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic connect-offsets --replication-factor 3 --**partitions 50** --config cleanup.policy=compact

**status.storage.topic=connect-status**

bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic connect-status --replication-factor 3 --**partitions 10** --config cleanup.policy=compact

I understand why connect-configs has only one partition, it has to be unique partition, ok.
But i don´t understand and i can not get information on why connect-offsets should have 50 partitions and connect-status 10

Comment: It more-or-less puts an upper limit on the amount of Connect workers you can have in the cluster. If you don't need a large cluster, you can make it smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a guess but partitions spread the load on a topic.

I don't know what is the exact function of each of these topics but if I had to guess I'd say that `configs` is probably not continuously accessed since looks like it stores configurations. `status` most likely is periodically updated but not as often of `offsets`. And `offsets` is updated by source connectors all the time.

So maybe the documentation creates the topics with these number of partitions based on expected load, and it explicitly sets them to not rely on the default number of partitions when creating a topic.

For example in [here](https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.3/connect/userguide.html#distributed-worker-configuration) it says

> `offset.storage.partitions`
>
> The number of partitions used when Connect creates the topic used to store connector offsets. A **large value (e.g., 25 or 50, just like Kafka’s built-in __consumer_offsets topic) is necessary to support large Kafka Connect clusters.**

and

> `status.storage.partitions`
>
> The number of partitions used when Connect creates the topic used to store connector and task status updates.
>
> Default: 5

which defaults to a small number

Comment: Offsets topic is actually used by source connectors (producers into Kafka from external sources that support offset tracking) not consumers. That's what `__consumer_offsets` is for

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I've edited the answer to note that